Facing problem to retrieve product data from ConnectAPI - Guest User
i'm currently working on a Project that have B2B module, and i'm trying to retrieve product data from ConnectApi.CommerceCatalog.getProduct to a Guest User, but when i call the Apex controller, this exception is being thrown: ConnectApiException:[errorCode=INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS]: Unable to retrieve product information.
We do not have a Contact for this Guest User, i just created a MDT that contains a AccountID related to the Store Location (US, MX, Brazil) based on the location a retrieve this AccountID from MDT and pass it to the ConnectAPI.
ALl of our Buyer Groups and entitlements is related to Accounts.
